# What are possible reasons why Google script with hourly trigger ran 3 times within several minutes?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, triggers

My script at G AppsScript ran more often than the trigger is set for.

The purpose of the script is to check Gmail inbox every hour and if an automated email was not delivered - alert a slack channel.

There is an automation that delivers email to the Gmail address every hour, Gmail rules add a label to the emails. The script checks for the label, if found - the label is removed, the email is marked as read. When there is no label - webhook url is triggered to send an alert.

However, now the code was executed 3 times within an hour instead of 1 time as trigger is set. This resulted in 2 notifications to slack.
Could someone help to understand what is wrong?

trigger[image]
executions[image]

```
function parseEmailByLabel() {
var gmailLabelName = "ParseThis",
    externalHandlerScript = "https://hooks.slack.com/workflows/T1234",
    gmailLabelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabelName),
    threads = gmailLabelObject.getThreads(),
    messages,
    message,
    params,
    response;



if (threads != "") {
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
            message = messages[j];
            message.markRead();
        }
        threads[i].removeLabel(gmailLabelObject);
    }
} else if (threads == "") {
    params = {
        'method': 'post',
    };
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(externalHandlerScript, params).getContentText();
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

}

Comment: You may have created more than one trigger

Comment: Most likely multiple triggers as others mentioned, but let us know if that's not the case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. There is only one trigger. I do not see an option to add a screenshot, so here's the link to a screenshot https://katuborodina.tinytake.com/msc/NzA2MDQ5Ml8xOTc5NzE4Ng

Comment: Since it seems you cannot reproduce it anymore it's hard to tell if it was a one-time bug or what happened, but keep in mind that according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), you cannot see triggers installed from another account, so if multiple users have are working on the project that could be a cause.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created more than one trigger. You may check here:

https://script.google.com/home/triggers

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. there is only 1 trigger

Comment: @Ekaterina  Delete it and re add it.

Comment: thank you for your advice. It did not malfunction since the last episode, I did not do any changes. I will do if it happens again. Do you think it is a bug?

Comment: @Ekaterina  Maybe. But without being able to reproduce it, there's little we can say or do.